# why getting wrong result while multiplying in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
var x = .06;
var y = x * 100;

var x2 = .07;
var y2 = x2 * 100;


console.log(y)  // output is 6, as expected

console.log(y2) // output 7.000000000000001, why not just 7?
```

Why i am getting `7.000000000000001` instead of `7`. How to get 7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: You can get the answer you want like this: `y2.toFixed()`

Comment: Why it's because of little endian